# Compare an expression with a key in handlebars with the help of a helper

Tags: if-statement, handlebars.js, expression, helper

I have a helper defined as

```
'ifCond': function(v1, v2, options) {
      if(v1 === v2) {
        return options.fn(this);
      }             
      return options.inverse(this);
    }
}
```

Now in the place of v1 and v2, i have an expression called as {{index}} and a {{@key}} from an {{each}}.I want to equate them both..

When i use the helper in my hbs as following,

```
{{#ifCond {{index}} {{@key}} }}
    <p> Hello </p>
{{else}}
    <p> Not Hello </p>
{{/ifCond}}
```

I get this error

```
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR',        'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN',   'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'OPEN'enter code here
```

How should i solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use braces inside of your helper call use index or @key without {{}} around them.

```
{{#ifCond index @key }}
```

Also as you did not use @index I suppose you are using a each statement like that :

```
{{#each elements as |index| }}
```

Comment: Understood. Found the solution. Thanks a ton. :)